# なぜ重みの初期値にnp.random.randnを用いるのか？

Tags: python, 機械学習, ニューラルネットワーク

**質問１**

「ゼロから作るディープラーニング」を勉強していて、182pのところを読んでいたら、そもそもなんで、重みWの初期値を今までnp.random.randnというものにしていたのかがわからなくなりました。なのでなぜnp.random.randnを重みの初期値にするのかを教えていただきたいです。

**質問２**
np.random.randnは「平均0、分散1（標準偏差1）の正規分布（標準正規分布）に従う乱数を返す。」とネットに書いてあったのですが、この意味もよくわかりません。試しに下のようにコードを実行して、平均が０になるのかと思ったら0になりませんでした。この文章の意味を教えていただきたいです。

```
tu = np.random.randn(1,100)

tuuu=0

for i in range(100):
    tuuu += tu[0][i]
print(tuuu/100)
# 出力0.22453386331188382 ※毎回違う、平均０じゃないじゃんと思いました。
```

Comment: [Mean of normal distribution generated using numpy.random.randn() is not '0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321328)

Comment: 「わからなくなりました」「なぜnp.random.randnを重みの初期値に」…では, 何を疑問に思ってるのか伝わりにくいかも。回答として「勾配が必要」「そのための初期値」と記したけど, 人によって「勾配って何」あるいは「そんな程度知ってるよ」などの意見もあるかも。ということで「こう考えたが何か違うか？」など状況とか, ディープラーニングの手法([例えば](https://qiita.com/ishizakiiii/items/4ea799a47f70a45b687c))とか, 質問に詳細加えるとよいかも

Answer (score 3):

##### 重み (Weight) の初期値をなぜ np.random.randn にするのか

[ゼロから作るDeepLearning 6章を学ぶ 〜重みの初期値について〜](https://www.takapy.work/entry/2018/06/14/221633) の記事が詳しいかも
勾配がゼロになると学習が進まなくなるので, 勾配損失が起きないような初期値を与えることは大切です

[ニューラルネットワークの学習でしていること](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/2004/27/news020.html) なども参考になるかも？

---

##### np.random.randnは「平均0、分散1（標準偏差1）の正規分布（標準正規分布）」

サイコロ振って 5回とも違う目が出て, 6回目は残ってる最後のひとつに決まってる … などということはありません。
99回の乱数出たあと, 残りひとつでちょうど平均ゼロになったなら, 「numpy.random さん, 仕事しろ !!」って話になります

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
num = []
mean = []
std = []
for cnt in range(1, 1200):
    data = np.random.randn(cnt)
    num.append(cnt)
    mean.append(data.mean())
    std.append(data.std())

ax.scatter(num, mean, label='mean')
ax.set_xlabel('count')
ax.set_ylabel('mean')
ax.legend(loc=4)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.scatter(num, std, color='r', label='std')
ax2.set_ylabel('std')
ax2.legend(loc=1)
```

試しに作ってみました。5万とか 10万くらいで, 滑らかに, 平均0、分散1 に**近づいて**いきます

[image: 実行結果]

Comment: 「平均0、分散1」については, サンプル数少ないと振り幅が大きいので, それなりのサンプル数がないと, 平均 0 に近いかどうかわかりにくい…ということで

Answer (score -1):

[このサイト](https://teratail.com/questions/343724)を見ればわかると思います。teratailで回答をしてくださった方がいます。